# angularjs get html inner value of the label inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Hello I want to get the value of one label with `angularjs` and I have tried with:

```
var photoName=angular.element('label[id=photoLbId]').val();
```

and the result is undefined meanwhile for an input type radio is working

```
var ans1 = angular.element('input[name=answer1]:checked').val();
```

How could I get the html value of the label with angularjs?
here is the html code for label :

```
<ul id="navlist" style="list-style: none; width: 1000px;">
    <li ng-repeat="item in stepsUrlPhotosList track by $index"  style="display: inline; width: 1000px;">
       <label id="photoLbId" for="photoId">{{item.name}}</label>
       <img id="photoId" style="width: 30%;max-height:300px ;" ng-src="{{item.photoUrl}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the directive from angular code:

```
app.directive('quiz',['$http',function(answerList1) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller : ['$scope', '$http','answerList1',, function ($scope,$http,answerList1) {


            $scope.checkAnswer1 = function() {

                console.log('Checking elements..... '+angular.element('input[name=answer1]:checked').val());

                var ans1 = angular.element('input[name=answer1]:checked').val();


                console.log('Checking label.....'+angular.element('label[id=photoLbId]').val());
                var photoName=angular.element('label[id=photoLbId]').val();

                answerList1.push(photoName+' '+ ans1);
            };
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`$scope`** variable and you can access the variable and get the value through **`ng-click`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.stepsUrlPhotosList= 
     [{
        "OwnerID": 1,
        "Comment": "Charlotte is brilliant. A lovely person. Thank you!",
        "rating": 4
      }, {
        "OwnerID": 2,
        "Comment": "The best dog carer ever! She is amazing",
        "rating": 4
      }]    ;  
  
    $scope.display = function(item){
       alert(item.rating);
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in stepsUrlPhotosList" ng-click="display(item)">
          {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi thank you for the help but my angular code is in a directive and the controller is created dynamically so I cannot use your solution , I want to access the html label element from angular something similar with document.getElementById("myId")

Comment: post your directive

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
var El = angular.element(document.querySelector('#photoLbId'));
var value = El.val();
```

Comment: I got undefined although I have added also at value attribute the iterated resulted value:  <label id="photoLbId" for="photoId" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>